# Scroll div images horizontally using arrow <a> tag without JQUERY

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling

I need to scroll a set of images HOROZONTALLY in a div on clicking the left and right arrow (anchor tags) using pure javascript. I see lot number of solutions using jquery. But for some reason I cannot use jquery in my site. My code is below. Any help is much appreciated. I need to implement something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/yfqyq9a9/2/ without jquery.

```
<div class="ImageContainer">
<a id="prevPageButton" href="#" class="prevPageButton"  role="button"></a>
<div class="SKUImages-wrapper">

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image1" src="01.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image2" src="02.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image3" src="03.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image4" src="04.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image5" src="05.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image6" src="06.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image7" src="07.jpg" alt="" />

                <img itemprop="image" id="Image8" src="08.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
    <div class="nextPageButton-wrap"
    <a id="nextPageButton" href="#" class="nextPageButton" role="button" ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in javascript? If so, could you also post what you tries here?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this so far. I tried some slide bar stuff but that is not the requirement

Comment: @JustinPearce  I have added a working solution to this. One another thing am looking at is, on clicking the right arrow, when it reaches the last image, is there a way to scroll to the first image ?

Comment: @AndrewL Added the code below

Answer (score 1):

I got a working solution for this. onClick of the anchor tag added the below function.

```
sideScroll : function (direction,speed,distance,step){
        var element = document.getElementById('ImageContainer');
        var scrollAmount = 0;
        var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(direction == 'left'){
                element.scrollLeft -= step;
            } else {
                element.scrollLeft += step;
            }
            scrollAmount += step;
            if(scrollAmount >= distance){
                window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
            }
        }, speed);
    }
```